# React Typescript useReducer not accepting the initial state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";

enum ICONACTIONKIND {
  SetValue = "SetValue",
  SetActive = "SetActive",
}

interface ACTIONTYPE {
  type: ICONACTIONKIND;
  payload: PAYLOADKIND;
}

export interface ICONDATAKIND {
  iconProgress: number;
  highlightColor: string;
  activeColor: string;
  nowActive: boolean;
  behaviour: string;
  icon: string;
}

interface PAYLOADKIND {
  value: number;
  active: boolean;
}

function micReducer(state: ICONDATAKIND, action: ACTIONTYPE) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case ICONACTIONKIND.SetValue:
      return { ...state, value: (state.iconProgress = action.payload.value) };
    case ICONACTIONKIND.SetActive:
      return { ...state, value: (state.iconProgress = action.payload.value) };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const StatsIcon: React.FC = () => {
  const defaultValues: ICONDATAKIND = {
    iconProgress: 40,
    highlightColor: "#7ef542",
    activeColor: "#d9d923",
    nowActive: false,
    behaviour: "whenabovezero",
    icon: "micIcon.png",
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(micReducer,  defaultValues );

  function checkVisibility() {
    let visible = true;
    if (behaviour === "always-on") {
      return true;
    } else if (behaviour === "whenabovezero") {
      iconProgress > 0 ? (visible = true) : (visible = false);
    } else if (behaviour === "whenbelowhundred") {
      iconProgress < 100 ? (visible = true) : (visible = false);
    }
    return visible;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {checkVisibility() && (
        <div
          className="statsicon"
          style={{
            background: `linear-gradient( to top,${
              nowActive ? activeColor : highlightColor
            } 0%,${
              nowActive ? activeColor : highlightColor
            } ${iconProgress}%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%)`,
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <img src={`/src/assets/images/${icon}`} height={20} />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default StatsIcon;
```

I know that correct props are not passed to the rendered components. the values are doing to come from the useReducer "state" but the inital state arg is giving error can anyone help to fix this and tell me what is wrong with the code.
This is the error on the useReducer function:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: ICONDATAKIND, action: ACTIONTYPE) => { value: number; iconProgress: number; highlightColor: string; activeColor: string; nowActive: boolean; behaviour: string; icon: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
      Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: ICONDATAKIND, action: ACTIONTYPE) => { value: number; iconProgress: number; highlightColor: string; activeColor: string; nowActive: boolean; behaviour: string; icon: string; }, initialState: { ...; }, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ICONDATAKIND' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ value: number; iconProgress: number; highlightColor: string; activeColor: string; nowActive: boolean; behaviour: string; icon: string; }'.
      Property 'value' is missing in type 'ICONDATAKIND' but required in type '{ value: number; iconProgress: number; highlightColor: string; activeColor: string; nowActive: boolean; behaviour: string; icon: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be returning state like this

```
case ICONACTIONKIND.SetValue:
  return { ...state, iconProgress: action.payload.value }
```

also inside the StatsIcon component you are referencing state variables directly without using the state object.

```
if (state.behaviour === "always-on") //do this
if (behaviour === "always-on") // instead of this
```

Also consider using this type of approach to keep things simple. It is much cleaner when action.type is a primitive instead of an object.

```
type ICONACTIONKIND = "SetValue" | "SetActive";

interface ACTIONTYPE {
  type: ICONACTIONKIND;
  payload: PAYLOADKIND;
}
```